# Cardano-cli requires signing key to be a file, fails with a named pipe

Tags: cardano-cli, security, signing-key-file, encryption

Please see the discussion here.  https://forum.cardano.org/t/cardano-cli-signing-a-transaction-without-directly-accessing-the-skey-file-in-plain-text/103742/11

cardano-cli should be able to read signing keys from a named pipe to maintain a high level of security while handling keys, a bug report was submitted but no further interactions.
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/4101

Thoughts? Alternative approaches? Maybe we can flag someone from IOG who can help clarify if this has been discussed and is a design choice or is it really a "bug".

Comment: If you want to formalise this for deeper consideration and discussion then a Cardano Improvement Proposal (CIP) could be raised at https://cips.cardano.org/

Answer (score 0):

I can also add this here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/4235

the process substitution is working for some parameters, for some not.

Comment: Good catch too! These little details really help maintain a high level of security when dealing with keys.